# discerning usages of "as"

Tags: conjunctions, as

> It was no longer possible to enter the temple, for it had filled with rubble years ago, but they admired the exterior, ***as did*** all the tourists Mr. Kapasi brought there, slowly strolling along each of its sides.

Another sentence -

> He plays the piano ***as does*** she.

My specific question:

Is the **function** of **as**  which has been used in the two sentences the same?

Comment: I will tell you, but can you please tell me what is the parts of speech of **as** in these sentences? It's easy.

Comment: It is merely conjunction

Comment: nima -- The words "just", "merely", and "simply" are more important than they seem.  They can [reveal the essence](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?JustIsaDangerousWord) of something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example sentences **as** is a conjunction.

**As**

*(conjunction)* In the same manner or way that:

**Example -**

> Think as I think.

As a conjunction **as** introduces a clause that is sometimes inverted. There **as** mean **so or likewise**.

> He went to military school **as** did his friend. [= *He went to the military school, his friend also went there.*]

Your example sentence -

> It was no longer possible to enter the temple, for it had filled with rubble years ago, but they admired the exterior, **as** *[did all the tourists]* (that) Mr. Kapasi brought there, slowly strolling along each of its sides.

Here **as** introduces the clause - *[did all the tourists]*

***did*** means ***admired*** here.

But you might be thinking why in that subordinate clause - *[did all the tourists]* - the subject-verb is inverted.

There are reasons. Firstly it sounds better that way, and secondly it's to keep the antecedent of ***that*** - **the tourists** - close to *that*-clause - *(that) Mr. Kapasi brought there.*

Your second sentence -

> He plays the piano **as** does she. [= *Both of them play piano*]

But the non-inverted version means something different.

> He plays the piano **as** she does. [it might mean the same as above or this - *He plays the piano the same way as she plays*]

Comment: Thanks. But, they are not my specific answer.

Comment: @nima wait for some time. I have to edit my answer. This answer is not completely correct. In the mean time can you please add your specific question?

Comment: Of course, why not ok

Comment: @nima I will come back in a few minutes. Give me some time.